# How to use CameraEffect in Androidx

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-camerax

I wanted to implement an app that performs continuous capture like the one implemented in Grafika. I want to use androidx to do this, and I've come to the understanding that I could use the CameraEffect API on the Preview use case to somehow get the frames, save them in a buffer, and display the preview. My question is, how can I use CameraEffect? I tried looking for examples of CameraEffect and found the one on the AndroidX GitHub repository for the integration tests ([link](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/androidx-main/camera/integration-tests/viewtestapp/src/main/java/androidx/camera/integration/view/ToneMappingSurfaceProcessor.kt)).

One problem is that if I copy the code for implementing my own surface processor, I get an error (can only be called from within the same library group (referenced groupId=androidx.camera from groupId=Jetpack)). Can anyone tell me if the approach I am taking is correct and, if so, how I can fix/use the example?

Comment: If there is an internal API you want to use, You can suppress the warning and use it. Which API gives you the warning?

Comment: Mainly this: androidx.camera:camera-core!

Comment: There should be a specific API that gives you the error. If you let me know I can look into it. Also, the "same library group" error can be suppressed so it won't be a blocker.